# Can't print PDF in webView using Swift 3, wants baseURL with initializers

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3, base-url

My `iOS` project built in `Swift2` using `Xcode7` had a feature where the user could print a PDF stored in app memory that was displayed in a `webView`.  Worked great and would print to the nearby wifi printer.  I used the migration tool to convert it to `Swift3` and it is now having problems with wanting a `baseURL` that has initializers:

```
    if buttonPressed == "Print" {

        // Create a coded WebView only; not visible
        let printWebView: UIWebView = UIWebView()

        // Load the converted PDF Data to the WebView
        printWebView.load(pdfData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: URL())

        ...

    }
```

Worked fine before I started using `Swift3`  How do I fix this?, Previously it is working with `NSURL()`. The PDF is a saved on in the app memory that they can view and then print.  Could the PDF itself act as a baseURL?   I looked online and couldn't find anything that would help. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have read the same issue, try once `if let url = NSURL().absoluteURL {` now use this url object with  baseURL

Comment: I ended up using this and nestling the code within this if statement and using the 'url' as the baseURL.  Worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `absoluteURL` property with empty `NSURL()` like this.

```
if let url = NSURL().absoluteURL {
    printWebView.load(pdfData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: url)
}
```